# Program in C with creating Nodes and Packets

Tags: c, computer-science

This is the original program instructions: https://prnt.sc/rgf0we

This is what I've done so far. Can someone help me as to why all the nodes output the same number of nodes created and nodes returned? I've created the basis for this program, but for some reason, the output is the same for every single node.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node
{
    int data;
    int created, returned, NotReturned;
    struct node *next;
}*node;

void Nodecreated(int createNode);
void CreatePacket(int j);

int main()
{
    int createNode, j;
    j = 100;
    printf("How many node should be made: "); /*askes the user to input how many nodes wants to be created*/
    scanf("%d", &createNode);
    Nodecreated(createNode);
    return 0;
}
/*A function that can create nodes based off of the users input*/
void Nodecreated(int createNode)
{
    struct node *next, *newNode,*temp, *fnNode;
    int num, i;
    /*creates the first node to the linked list*/
    newNode = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    for(i = 1; i <= createNode; i++)
    {
        /*creates a node and gives it an id which is then transverse to the other nodes*/
        fnNode = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        fnNode -> data = i;
        printf("----------------------\n");
        printf("node %d\n", i);
        CreatePacket(100);/*A function to create another linked list that will count the packets*/
        next = fnNode -> next;
        temp = next;
    }

}

void CreatePacket(int j)
{
    int totalcreated, totalreturned;
    struct node node1, node2, node3, node4;
    node1.created = 0;
    node1.returned = 0;
    node2.created = 0;
    node2.returned = 0;
    node3.created = 0;
    node3.returned = 0;
    node4.NotReturned = 0;
    /*goes through a loop 100 times and whenever i is a multiples of the 3 it will create a packet*/
    for(int n = 1; n <= j; n++)
    {
        if(n % 2 == 0)
        {
            node1.created = node1.created + 1;
            node1.returned = node1.returned + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            node4.NotReturned = node4.NotReturned + 1;   
        }
        if(n % 3 == 0)
        {
            node2.created = node2.created + 2;
            node2.returned = node2.returned + 2;
        }
        else
        {
            node4.NotReturned = node4.NotReturned + 1;
        }
        if(n % 5 == 0)
        {
            node3.created = node3.created + 3;
            node3.returned = node3.returned + 3;
        }
        else
        {
            node4.NotReturned = node4.NotReturned + 1;  
        }
    }
    /*tally up all the packets created and returned as well as the packets that haven't been created and prints it out*/
    totalreturned = node1.returned + node2.returned + node3.returned;
    totalcreated = node1.created + node2.created + node3.created;
    printf("Packets created: %d\n", totalcreated);
    printf("Packets returned: %d\n", totalreturned);
    printf("Packets left out: %d\n", node4.NotReturned);
    printf("----------------------\n");
}
```

Comment: Your linking is quite wrong. For example `next = fnNode -> next;` doesn't make sense because `fnNode->next` has not been initialised, `temp = next;` also doesn't make sense because you never use `temp` and `newNode = malloc` is useless as you never use `newNode`.

Comment: So what should I add to my code? I'm still confused